# Weird-looking curve in DRL

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning, tensorboard

I have a deep reinforcement learning agent that interacts with a customized environment and I am displaying the reward value every episode using tensorboard.
The curve looks like this

[image: Curve]

For some reason it jumps to step 80 after step 17 every time and I cannot understand why, I don't even know what part of the code I should copy paste here.

Anyone has any idea why it does that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the step number is getting incremented elsewhere, commented that line and it works fine now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).